# Custom field and list view totals

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom, custom-field-types

I have created a custom field that inerits from a SPFieldMultiColumn. It stores the area size like this:

> 10;#km
>
> 25;#km

I want to use this field in totals for list view. Is it possible to summarize the numerical values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating new calculate column, get numerical values from your SPFieldMultiColumn to this calculated column and then summarize by this new calculated column like in this [post](http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2012/12/03/jennys-sharepoint-tip-sum-calculated-columns/)